# Show popup on hover - mapbox

Tags: popup, hover, mapbox, geojson

I want to display the popup about the marker on hover (not click). I have looked at all the examples on Mapbox (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-hover/) -

however the issue in the example is its pulling the locations and descriptions from a layer in the script... where as I would like it to show the data from my dataset layer ['mydata']

The code below works for clicking on the marker - I simply would like it to work on hover.

```
<script>

        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'example-token'; // replace this with your access token
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'example-style' // replace this with your style URL
        });

        // code from the next step will go here

        map.on('click', function(e) {
            var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
                layers: ['pillbox-data'] // replace this with the name of the layer
            });

            if (!features.length) {
                return;
            }

            var feature = features[0];

            var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
                    offset: [0, -15]
                })
                .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
                .setHTML('<h3>' + feature.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + feature.properties.description + '</p>')
                .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
                .addTo(map);
        });

        map.addControl(new MapboxGeocoder({
            accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken
        }));


</script>
```

Comment: Found this demo which shows how to do this https://jsfiddle.net/rasagy/sy0j1nqj/

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use on 'mousemove' instead of on 'click'. After you initialize your map, insert this code. It's a Mapbox tileset, so your access token should work.

```
// Create a popup, but don't add it to the map yet.
var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
    closeButton: false
});

map.on('load', function() {
    // Add the source to query. In this example we're using
    // county polygons uploaded as vector tiles
    map.addSource('counties', {
        "type": "vector",
        "url": "mapbox://mapbox.82pkq93d"
    });

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "counties",
        "type": "fill",
        "source": "counties",
        "source-layer": "original",
        "paint": {
            "fill-outline-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)",
            "fill-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)"
        }
    }, 'place-city-sm'); // Place polygon under these labels.

    map.on('mousemove', 'counties', function(e) {
        // Change the cursor style as a UI indicator.
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';

        // Single out the first found feature.
        var feature = e.features[0];

        // Display a popup with the name of the county
        popup.setLngLat(e.lngLat)
            .setText(feature.properties.COUNTY)
            .addTo(map);
    });

    map.on('mouseleave', 'counties', function() {
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
        popup.remove();
    });
});
```